# Optimizing permutation of a large array

Tags: python, optimization

I have a programming problem that seemed simple but I couldn't find a satisfying solution to.

I have two lists `l1` and `l2` of the same length (about 500000 entries) and I want to permute `l1` to make it as similar to `l2` as possible by minimizing the error defined as follows (in Python):

```py
error = sum((l1[i] - l2[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(l1)))
```

I was hoping to find some python library that does this, I tried `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but it failed because it couldn't allocate 8TB of memory.

My solution doesn't need to be perfect. The simple algorithm I came up with was to pick two random indices, `p1` and `p1`, and swap them if swapping improves the error. I repeat that 15000000 times and get an acceptable result:

```py
for iteration in range(15000000):
    p1, p2 = random.randrange(0, len(l1)), random.randrange(0, len(l1))
    err_before = (l2[p1] - l1[p1])**2 + (l2[p2] - l1[p2])**2
    err_after = (l2[p1] - l1[p2])**2 + (l2[p2] - l1[p1])**2
    if err_after < err_before:
        l1[p1], l1[p2] = l1[p2], l1[p1]
```

Is there a simple algorithm or maybe a library that can do this more efficiently?

Comment: Exactly what you are asking is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968409/efficient-algorithm-to-find-the-permutation-that-reduces-distance-between-two-li).